# How to create an ISO image that is mountable with Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, mount, iso-image

I have a directory of 1 TB with thousands of small files on `ext3` filesystem. Now I want to put it all in an ISO image and send it to Windows with `NTFS` filesystem. I wonder whether I will be able to mount the image created with the following command in Windwos?

```
genisoimage -o output_image.iso directory_name
```

Comment: do you thought of simply .zip them? maybe this is a more efficent way, because WIN can browse .zip files like usual Directorys ;)

Comment: @chris yes I did. zip runs out of memory for that huge amount of files :(

Comment: Windows 8.x and above can mount any .ISO out of the box provided it has a filesystem it understands of course ( ext3 it would not understand ).

Comment: it seems like it would be better to target a more neutral filesystem type like UDF. I wouldn't trust linux to implement the NTFS conversion. Of course you could install ext drivers for windows, if you are not looking for compabili9ty outside your home.

Comment: @Aley, do you try to create a tarball? as far as i know the tar-command can`t run out of Memory. On win you can open this with 7-zip for example

Comment: @chris I didn't but thats an option, yes. I will try it now with 7za that also supports multithread and skips out all permission, owner meta data stuff.

Comment: A 1TB ISO is a bad idea because it is quite literally, not ISO complaint. NTFS is also not ISO compliant. You should use a tool specifically designed for the purpose, such as ZIP or TAR or 7Zip. If you want to create an image, you are better off creating a hard drive image, not an ISO.

Comment: I will use 7zip for now. But may you tell me whether it is possible to create a hard drive image that is mountable in windows?